# Why is $Ω(H) ≤ Ω(\hat{H}) + \langle ∇Ω(\hat{H}), H − \hat{H} \rangle$ true?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations, tangent-line

I read this [paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~dlsun/papers/universal_speech_models.pdf), it provides a short information for majorizing function  $Ω(H)$ which is log function (concave).

At before equation 4,

> $Ω(\hat{H})$ denotes the value of $H$ at the current iteration. Next,
>   since $Ω$ is concave, we can majorize it by its tangent at $Ω(H) ≤ Ω(\hat{H}) + \langle ∇Ω(\hat{H}), H − \hat{H} \rangle$

What I know is this should relate to the majorization of log function $log(θ) ≤ log(θ′) + θ/θ′ − 1$ since $Ω(H)$ is log function. But I don't understand how the term $\langle ∇Ω(\hat{H}), H − \hat{H} \rangle$ come from?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I updated my question.

Comment: the term comes from the linear approximation (first order Taylor expansion)